# Convert Stacked DataFrame of Years and Months to DataFrame with Datetime Indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file of the number of employees in the US by year and month (in thousands). It starts out like this:

```
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
1961,45119,44969,45051,44997,45119,45289,45400,45535,45591,45716,45931,46035
1962,46040,46309,46375,46679,46668,46644,46720,46775,46888,46927,46910,46901
1963,46912,47000,47077,47316,47328,47356,47461,47542,47661,47805,47771,47863
...
```

**I want my Pandas Dataframe to have the datetime as the index for each month's value**. I'm doing this so I can later add values for specific time ranges. I want it to look something like this:

```
1961-01-01      45119.0
1961-02-01      44969.0
1961-03-01      45051.0
1961-04-01      44997.0
1961-05-01      45119.0
...
```

I did some research and thought that if I stacked the years and months together, I could combine them into a datetime. Here is what I have done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("BLS_private.csv", header=5, index_col="Year")
df.columns = range(1, 13)  # I transformed months into numbers 1-12 for easier datetime conversion
df = df.stack()  # Months are no longer columns
print(df)
```

Here is my output:

```
Year    
1961  1      45119.0
      2      44969.0
      3      45051.0
      4      44997.0
      5      45119.0
...
```

I do not know how to combine the year and the months in the stacked indices. Does stacking the indices help at all in my case? I am also not the most familiar with Pandas datetime, so any explanation about how I could use that would be very helpful. Also if anyone has alternate solutions than making datetime the index, I welcome ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `stack` create the DateTimeIndex from the current index

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_index = pd.to_datetime([datetime(year=year, month=month, day=1)
                    for year, month in df.index.values])
df.index = dt_index
df.head(3)

# 1961-01-01    45119
# 1961-02-01    44969
# 1961-03-01    45051
```

Comment: That works great! I didn't know that df.index.values would return both parts of the index, so that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("BLS_private.csv", index_col="Year")
dates = pd.date_range(start=str(df.index[0]), end=str(df.index[-1] + 1), closed='left', freq="MS")
df = df.stack()
df.index = dates
df.to_frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
1961,45119,44969,45051,44997,45119,45289,45400,45535,45591,45716,45931,46035
1962,46040,46309,46375,46679,46668,46644,46720,46775,46888,46927,46910,46901
1963,46912,47000,47077,47316,47328,47356,47461,47542,47661,47805,47771,47863"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))   

# set index and stack
stack = df.set_index('Year').stack().reset_index()
# create  a new index
stack.index = pd.to_datetime(stack['Year'].astype(str) +'-'+ stack['level_1'])
# remove columns
final = stack[0].to_frame()

1961-01-01    45119
1961-02-01    44969
1961-03-01    45051
1961-04-01    44997
1961-05-01    45119
1961-06-01    45289
```